# Quote messing Attribute title

Tags: php, html

I have a snippet like this:

```
echo "<a title='" . $row['title'] . "' />" //and so on
```

now everything is a mess when $row['title'] contains something like this:

- The Great's title
- The "Great" title

What is the best procedure to retain the word in my title and not break the title for the anchor tag

My solution is not that effective using `str_replace` any good ideas to handle this?

Comment: How is it messing with your string if it's already stored in a variable `$row['title']`? (so the characters must be escaped)

Comment: I think you need to be a little clearer in how you word your question. Showing us some more code may help.

Comment: You should really practice the more widely accepted practice of using double quotes for HTML element attributes

Comment: @MikeBrant , I know what you mean, but since the data are coming from a customized CMS and editor input a title something like `title's` or `"titles"` when inserted to title attribute it's messing the anchor tag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704547/display-a-php-variable-that-contain-quotes

Comment: @RakeshSharma thanks! that gave me an idea

Comment: use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) -> `echo "<a title='" . htmlspecialchars($row['title']) . "' />"` from the docs -Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings. This function returns a string with these conversions made. eg. *'"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;'* and *"'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;)*

Comment: @Sean Have another look at the [manual page of `htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) regarding the single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `The Great's title` as  title, the output looks like this:

```
<a title='The Great's title' />
```

Here the attribute value ends prematurely after `Great`.

You need to [escape the attribute value properly](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
echo "<a title='" . htmlspecialchars($row['title'], ENT_QUOTES) . "' />"
```

Now the output looks like this:

```
<a title='The Great&#39;s title' />
```

The interpreted attribute value is still `The Great's title`.

The same applies to `The "Great" title`, which then will look like:

```
<a title='The &quot;Great&quot; title' />
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Much better now

Answer (score 1):

Simple way

```
<a href="#" title="<?php echo $title; ?>">link</a>
```

Comment: this doesnt work when data title is like `my "Answer"`